# Executing a try inside of a while loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to send an email inside a while loop but if the sendmail fails, I want the script to log the error and continue:

while True:

```
input_state = GPIO.input(5)
if input_state == True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%y-%H%M%S")
    logging.debug('Motion detected at ' + now)
    name = 'tempimage.jpg'
    camera.capture(name)
    new_name = '/home/pi/image' + str(now) + '.jpg'
    os.rename(name, new_name)
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP( "smtp.gmail.com", 587 )
        server.starttls()
        server.login( '<login to gmail>', '<password>' )
        server.sendmail( 'Front Porch', '<myphone number>@vtext.com', 'Picture just taken on Front Porch' ) #Chuck
        server.close()
    else:
        logging.debug('Send of text failed ' + now)
    time.sleep(3)
else:
    now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%y-%H%M%S")
    logging.debug('No Motion ' + now)
    time.sleep(3)
```

When I execute this at boot it stalls at the try. I know this is a Duh moment in the making but really need it to work. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a `try` with no `except` or `finally`. This isn't going to stall at the `try`; this is going to outright fail to compile.

Comment: Perhapse you meant `except AppropriateExceptionType` instead of `else`.

Comment: You guys are awesome! I knew this had to be a Duh moment. Many thanks, adding an Except capture as below fixed everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input_state = GPIO.input(5)
if input_state == True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%y-%H%M%S")
    logging.debug('Motion detected at ' + now)
    name = 'tempimage.jpg'
    camera.capture(name)
    new_name = '/home/pi/image' + str(now) + '.jpg'
    os.rename(name, new_name)
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP( "smtp.gmail.com", 587 )
        server.starttls()
        server.login( '<login to gmail>', '<password>' )
        server.sendmail( 'Front Porch', '<myphone number>@vtext.com', 'Picture just taken on Front Porch' ) #Chuck
        server.close()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.debug('Send of text failed ' + now + 'Exception '+e)
    time.sleep(3)
else:
    now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%y-%H%M%S")
    logging.debug('No Motion ' + now)
    time.sleep(3)
```

Try this code (I used except, not else and recorded the exception).

Comment: Worked perfectly! Many thanks.